# Javascript multiply result returns weird result

Tags: javascript, math

I am getting weird result with javascript on browser.

```
9.95 * 100
```

It returns `994.9999999999` instead of `995`. How can I get 995 as expected?

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) only explains why, and no solution for workaround.

Comment: `Number((9.95 * 100).toFixed(0))`

Comment: To downvoter and duplicator, the question you marked as duplicate doesn't share solution, it only explains why.